# javascript regex - global replace issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting content from a textarea (which besides simple text may include html markup), and try to parse it and replace all occurences of "[File:#xx#]" with a string contained in an array.
So, lets say the contents of the textarea is in `var html`.
I do the following:

```
html = html.replace(/\[File:#(.*)#\]/g, 
                    function($0, $1){ return furls[$1]; });
```

everything works fine when the contents the text area are like this:

```
<img src="[File:#111#]" alt="image1" />
<img src="[File:#222#]" />
```

but when there is no line break between 2 elements witch have attribute with `[File:#xx#]` value, then the problem appears.
So, given this as the textarea's value:

```
<img src="[File:#111#]" alt="image1" /><img src="[File:#222#]" />
```

seems like it matces the first img's `[File:#111#` but closes it not with the first bracket,  rathen than the second one's. so, what gets replaced is all this:
`#]" alt="image1" /><img src="[File:#222`

What is wrong with my regular expression? How can i prevent this look-ahead from happening and stop at the first closing bracket?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the correct regex for your case would be:

```
/[File:#[\w]+#]/g
```

Why is this the case?

Because in your regex:

> The . Matches any character, except for line breaks if dotall is false.
>
> The * Matches 0 or more of the preceeding token. This is a greedy match, and will match as  many characters as possible before satisfying the next token.

And in the regex i've provided:

> The \w Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).

Comment: Thanks a lot Bogdan for replying. It's enough for what i currently need, but What if i need to support any character, like `[File:#http://test.com/file1?a=1&b=2#]`

Comment: If you want to add other characters in your search you could have a regex like: /[File:#[\w=&?/.]+#]/g This will match the example you provided in the comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's grabbing everything from the first # sign to the last one, because you're using (.*), which matches all characters. Try this instead, which limits the matched part to just numeric digits:

```
html = html.replace(/\[File:#([0-9]*)#\]/g, 
                function($0, $1){ return furls[$1]; });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying russell. File ids may contain letters as well, so i picked Bogdan's answer. Thanks again for bothering :)