# Why does filtering on this Javascript regular expression only match two out of three identical strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The easiest way to explain my question is with reference to this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRxOEP

I have three apparently identical inputs from customers

```
<span class="customer_country" id="SW1">, Switzerland</span>
<span class="customer_country" id="SW2">, Switzerland</span>
<span class="customer_country" id="SW3">, Switzerland</span>
```

but a javascript regex filter is only matching two of them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var c = $('.customer_country');

  var reg = new RegExp('swi','gi');

  c.filter(function(){

    return reg.test(this.innerHTML);

  }).each(function(){      

    $('ul').append("<li>Item with ID " + this.id + " Matched</li>");   

  });  


});
```

Results:

```
*Item with ID SW1 Matched
*Item with ID SW3 Matched
```

Can anyone help me understand why this would be happening?

Comment: Get rid of the "g" flag: `new RegExp("swi", "i")` or (simpler) `/swi/i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex - global replace issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944777/javascript-regex-global-replace-issue)

Comment: Hi @Pointy - can you explain why? Why would a greedy search cause the contents of the second span to be ignored?

Comment: I know this is a duplicated because I've provided at least one answer, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @Ambulare "g" does not mean "greedy", it means "global". The regular expression object is stateful, and "remembers" the position in the string where the last match ended. On the next call to `.test()`, it starts from that point instead of the beginning of the string. If you don't want that behavior, just leave off the "g".

Comment: see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWvbZj)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte + Pointy - That solved it. I confused the purpse of the g flag. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You and achieve the required result like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var c = $('.customer_country');

  var reg = new RegExp('Swi','g');

  c.each(function(k,v){
    console.log("asim"+v.innerHTML);
     var patt1 = /Swi/g;
       if((v.innerHTML).match(patt1)){
        $('ul').append("<li>Item with ID " + v.id+ " Matched</li>");   
       }              
  });


});
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNmNGv